# How do I add extra fields (and process them) to a YouTube API Browser Upload form?

Tags: php, forms, api, youtube

I'm using a form as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading) to upload a file to a Youtube account. Like this:

```
<form action="<?=$YTurl ?>?nexturl=http://localhost/update-video.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$YTtoken ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="testvalue1234"/>
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

But I'm planning to have more fields on the form and since the action is set to YouTube's server I can't process the remaining fields. Does anyone has a workaround for this? I'd expect YT to let me add custom parameters and kindly posting them back to me on the callback specified with nexturl.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up sending the other form fields via AJAX before submitting the form. I also identify the video with a session id hash to be sure it's being stored in the proper record. Here is the code in case it helps somebody (wrapped up into jquery.validate.js):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").validate({
            rules: { ... },
            messages: { ... },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                if ($('#video_file').val()) {
                    var data = {};
                    $('input').each(function() {
                        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'process.php', dataType: 'json', type: 'POST', data: data,
                        success: function(response) {
                            if (response.status == '200') {
                                url = '<?=$tokenArray['url']?>?nexturl=http://localhost/update-video.php?hash=' + response.sid;
                                $(form).attr('action', url);                                        
                                form.submit();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else if ($('#video_url').val()) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```